# Does Expression Blend 4 not automatically nest a new ControlTemplate within a Style anymore?

Tags: expression-blend

I have a onetime `Style` and corresponding `ControlTemplate` for a custom `HyperLinkButton` in `Blend 4` (for Silverlight).

Documentation for Blend says :

> Control templates are wrapped inside
>   styles so that the style that is
>   applied to a control includes both the
>   appearance (parts) and the behavior
>   for the control. [(from here)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294894(Expression.40).aspx) and [(also here)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295273(v=Expression.40).aspx)

So I click my `HyperlinkButton` on the artboard and select `Object > Edit Template > Edit a copy` and I get:

```
<HyperlinkButton Template="{StaticResource HyperlinkButtonControlTemplate}"/>
```

Well thats not wrapped in a style is it!

SO I start over again and try to create a style with `Object > Edit Style > Edit a copy` and that gives me a new style, but no template (as expected):

```
<Style x:Key="HyperlinkButtonStyle2" TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
    <!--Setter Property="TargetName" Value="_new"/-->
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>          
    </Style>
```

Now I have a style with no control template. Then I select that style in `Styles.xaml` and do `Edit Template > Edit a copy` and it adds a linked ControlTemplate to the style:

```
<Style x:Key="HyperlinkButtonStyle2" TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
    <!--Setter Property="TargetName" Value="_new"/-->
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource HyperlinkButtonControlTemplate2}"/>

    </Style>
```

BUT The documentation for Blend 4 says that it will be created within a style, but it isn't. I absolutely see this as more flexible, but its not what I want becuase I don't want to reuse it and I'm wondering if this is configurable or I'm missing something .

**SO: Can I make Blend 4 create a `Style` and nested `ControlTemplate` at the same time or do I have to manually move the `ControlTemplate` into the `Style`?**

Answer (score 1):

It all depends in which mode you are.

If you follow a specific order of style and template creation, template does get embedded in a style. For example, create a button and do Object > Edit Style > Create Empty ( or Edit Current if you have already attached style to a button). You are in style editing mode. Now, **while in style editing mode**, select Object > Edit Template and create empty or copy template. It will be linked to style. This is 2 step process that you are following.

However, if you are **not in style editing mode**, selecting Object > Edit template > Copy creates style with linked template right away.

Comment: I'm looking around at all the 3 different places where you can create a style. It seems that a BUTTON will behave as I described, and a TEXTBOX works as you described. i.e. I cannot whatever I do get a regular BUTTON to create a style+template in a single step. i'm wondering if this is a bug since it doesn't seem to make much sense. hoping you're curious enough to try this yourself :-)

Comment: I can confirm you that for a Button I have the described behavior, style and template created in a single step. In fact, I never did tests on TextBox.I am using released version ob Blend, not RC - maybe that has to do with it?